# Flask request empty after redirect

Tags: python, request, flask

Using Flask, I'm able to access request.form data in the function poll(), but after a redirect, request.form is empty.

I'm sure this is intentional and I have to explicitly pass this, but how?

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, request

from app import app
from forms import PollForm

@app.route('/poll', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def poll():
    form = PollForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print request.form # returns ImmutableMultiDict with data
        return redirect('/details')

    return render_template('poll.html', form=form)

@app.route('/details')
def details():
    print request.form # returns empty ImmutableMultiDict
    return render_template('details.html')
```

Comment: Why do you need to redirect? Why not just display it on that page?

Comment: @Blender Is it standard practice to do things this way? I'm new to Flask and web in general, but that does make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common to redirect from a POST, but you shouldn't need your form data anymore in the details function.

You should process the form submission in the poll function and then redirect to details, which I assume would display some updated data - e.g. from a database.

```
@app.route('/poll', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def poll():
    form = PollForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # use request.form to update your database
        return redirect('/details')
    return render_template('poll.html', form=form)

@app.route('/details')
def details():
    # query the database to show the updated poll
    return render_template('details.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting in response to a POST request is pretty standard as it addresses weird browser behaviors around bookmarking and duplicate form submissions. The technique even has a name and a Wikipedia page: [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

To preserve the data from the POST request you have to use some form of per-user persistent storage. Possible options are a database, the user session (`flask.session`) or a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, I am not sure why you need redirect. You should just do:

```
@app.route('/poll', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def poll():
    form = PollForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return render_template('details.html', form = form)

    return render_template('poll.html', form=form)
```

You don't need the extra redundant view just to display details.In the view above, the key is in line

```
return render_template('details.html', form = form)
```

The above code supplies the form details to details.html template which then can easily parse the data and display it as needed.

However, if you really want to use redirect, then you could try using something like below. This way, you are able to pass the `form` to the redirect.

```
return redirect(url_for('details', form=form))
```